# Microsoft Word VBA macro to convert tracked changes to cross-references into text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to convert tracked changes in Microsoft Word into actual text with the underline/strikethrough. I have had difficulties in dealing with tracked changes with cross-references.

For instance, if a cross reference is updated, from paragraph 5 to 6, it would appear as "6<strike>5</strike>" [the 6 is underlined, but stackoverflow doesn't have that formatting option] I want to retain the 5 as raw text only, but keep the 6 as a cross-reference field.

I've gotten as far as the following macro which will do what I want if the cross reference has been /replaced/ with a new cross reference. However, it still does not work properly if the cross reference was only updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Sub TypeAndStrike()

Dim chgAdd As Word.Revision
Dim Colour
Colour = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Set the color to change the changes to.
'PD Colors: Black (0, 0, 0), Red (255, 0, 0), Green (0, 255, 0), Blue (0, 0, 255), Brown (165, 42, 42)

Dim SkipNext As Integer

' disable tracked revisions.
If ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "There are no revisions in this document", vbOKOnly
Else
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

For Each chgAdd In ActiveDocument.Revisions
If chgAdd.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then ' It's a deletion, so make it strike through and then reject the change (so the text isn't lost).

    SkipNext = 0
    chgAdd.Range.Select ' move insertion point

    chgAdd.Range.Font.StrikeThrough = True
    chgAdd.Range.Font.Color = Colour
        For Each testRange In Selection.Range.Fields ' Replace cross-refs with >text
        testRange.Select
        If Selection.Range = chgAdd.Range Then
            SkipNext = 1
        End If
        Selection.TypeText Text:=Selection.Text
        Next
    If SkipNext = 0 Then
    chgAdd.Range.Select
    chgAdd.Reject
    End If

ElseIf chgAdd.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then ' It's an addition, so underline it.

    chgAdd.Range.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    chgAdd.Range.Font.Color = Colour
    chgAdd.Accept
Else
    chgAdd.Range.Select ' move insertion point
End If

Next chgAdd
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked a lot with Revisions, so my suggestion may have drawbacks, however, it occurs to me that you might be able to do something with Field.Result.

A cross-reference is a REF field, under the covers - press Alt+F9 and you can toggle on the field code view to see it.

When code queries `ActiveDocument.Fields([index]).Result` a RANGE object is returned (a Range is returned for any Field.Result). `Result.Text` returns the visible result as plain text - in your example 65.

In and of itself, that's not useful. But if you combine it with, perhaps, `Result.Revisions.Count` you can find out how many revisions (if any) are stored in the field. Using your example, `Count` returns two and you know the first (left) is the change and the second (right) is the original. That should let you figure out what the value should be. You could then remove the field (`Field.Unlink`) and write the desired result to the document?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try play around with Result.Text as I haven't tried that yet.
Field.Unlink unfortunately removes the field for the changed result as well. What I'm trying to do is copy out the original result as text and retain the new crossreference.
I've been trying a variation of selecting the field, then doing a Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd, and Selection.TypeText. 
However, for some odd reason the typed text is typed INSIDE the field, so if the field is refreshed all the typed text is removed.

Comment: 1) You should be able to insert a new REF field to the same bookmark (those long numbers preceded by an underscore are hidden bookmark names). So if you want to keep the "live" cross-reference, store the bookmark name from the Field.Code before you unlink (delete) it.

Comment: 2) It might also work, with Track Changes off, to simply UPDATE the existing field after you've "captured" the information you need.

Comment: 3) If you press Alt+F9 to toggle on the field codes you'll see the field's "structures". When Selection is inside the field collapsing the Range may/probably leave/s the Selection within those structures. You might see if this gives a better result (pseudocode, and you'll need to separate this into code lines as Comments don't support writing code): Dim rng as Word.Range : Set rng = Field.Result : rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd